# C# - disable MinimizeBox, MaximizeBox and SizeBox on Chrome window

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I need to launch Chrome.exe and then disable MinimizeBox, MaximizeBox and SizeBox.
If I run this code with "notepad.exe" program it works.
You can see that notepad.exe window doesn't have MinimizedBox, MaximizedBox and you can't resize the window.
However, if I change "notepad.exe" to "chrome.exe" it doesn't work.
Resize is not possible but I still see MinimizedBox and MaximizedBox.
How to solve it ?
Many thanks
Sergio

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
public const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000;
public const int WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x10000;
public const int WS_SIZEBOX = 0x40000;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var proc = Process.Start("notepad.exe");  // this works
    //var proc = Process.Start("chrome.exe"); // this doesn't work
    proc.WaitForInputIdle();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // only for visual effect

    Int64 style = GetWindowLongPtr(proc.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE).ToInt64();
    style = style & (~(WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_SIZEBOX));
    SetWindowLongPtr(proc.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, (IntPtr)style);
}
```

I ran this code with C# VS2022, Windows Form, .NetFramework 4.8 and 64bit compiler

Comment: You're probably removing those buttons, but the buttons you see on screen are not the standard buttons of a window, those are *replicas*. The actual Caption of the window and  its buttons are hidden. This applies to also the Edge and FireFox browsers (and many other applications that style their windows, for many reasons. For example, so all look the same in different versions of the System)

Comment: You are right Jimi, very thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you click btnMin guess what happens

```
Public Sub btnMin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMin.Click
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub
```